# Calling LoadLibrary on a 64-bit dll from a 32-bit process

Tags: c++, x86, 64-bit, loadlibrary

I have a 32-bit exe that needs to dynamically load a 64-bit dll when it detects that the operating system is 64-bit. Is this possible through LoadLibrary? If not, is there another way to accomplish the same goal?

Comment: On a side note, the 32-bit instruction set is called "x86", not "x32". It doesn't really make sense these days, but I guess 8086 deserves to remembered :)

Answer (score 12):

As previously mentioned, 32-bit code cannot load 64-bit code in the same process. You'll have to load it into a different process (CreateProcess() ?) and use IPC to coordinate.

Comment: Here's a link to a set of ways of doing IPC on windows: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365574(VS.85).aspx. Also check out my answer on another thread for more ways of doing this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446411/remote-procedure-calls/446615#446615

Answer (score 2):

You can't mix 64-bit and 32-bit code in the same process. You'll need a 32-bit version of the DLL.