# Can we invoke functions of a DLL compiled for 64 bit using an application compiled for 32 bit?

Tags: c, windows, interop, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

Can we invoke functions of a DLL compiled for 64 bit using an application compiled for 32 bit?

I am using Windows 2008 64 bit system. But, the application is still compiled using 32 bit.

The code involves MFC & Windows SDK functions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling LoadLibrary on a 64-bit dll from a 32-bit process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466637/calling-loadlibrary-on-a-64-bit-dll-from-a-32-bit-process)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No.** A 32-bit application cannot load a 64-bit module into its process space (nor vice versa).

Remember that 32-bit processes are only supported on 64-bit versions of Windows in the dedicated Windows-on-Windows (WOW64) subsystem. That makes interoperability tricky at best. Raymond Chen's [blog entry on the subject](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/10/20/9006720.aspx) is quite instructive, if you care about the technical details.

You will either need to recompile one or the other, or load it into a separate process and use [interprocess communication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365574.aspx) to coordinate between the two.

Comment: If it's a COM library you might be able to load it as an out-of-process server, assuming the interface is marshallable...

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible.  Binary code included in the dll is different, and pointers are 64 bits.