# Can I Load Resource Library (DLL) for x64 build in x86 app?

Tags: x86, 64-bit, loadlibrary

I want to load unired.dll which used in default Windows Printer driver resource file.
I can load unires.dll for Windows Vista x86.

It's located in C:\Windows\System32\spool\drivers\w32x86\3

But now I use Windows 7 Pro x64.

So the same name unires.dll which is located in 
C:\Windows\System32\spool\drivers\x64\3 cannot be load.

By the following code,GetLastError() returns 193

Is it possible? or impossible ?
I use Visual Studio 2005 Pro. try build x64 and x86 but each of them failed.

```
TCHAR libName[MAX_PATH];
wsprintf(libName , _T("unires.dll"));

HINSTANCE hLibraryInstance = ::LoadLibrary(libName);
DWORD ErrorId=::GetLastError();

std::wofstream out;
out.open(_T("unires.txt"));

for(UINT resKey=0;resKey<100000;resKey++)
{

    TCHAR * resBuf=new TCHAR[CHAR_MAX]; 
    int BufferMaxSize=CHAR_MAX;
    int Result=::LoadString(hLibraryInstance, resKey, resBuf, BufferMaxSize);

    wstring resStr=resBuf;

    if(!resStr.empty())
    {
        out<<resKey;
        out<<" ";
        out<<resStr.c_str();
        out<<endl;
    }

    if(resBuf!=NULL)
    {
        delete [] resBuf;
    }
}

out.close();
```

Please help me.
Best regards!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling LoadLibrary on a 64-bit dll from a 32-bit process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466637/calling-loadlibrary-on-a-64-bit-dll-from-a-32-bit-process)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment link, you can't load a x64 library in a x86 process.

The solution might be to port your program to 64 bit.

Comment: Dear Mr.CharlesB. Thank you very much for your advice.It is very helpful for me. I try to my solution to port 64 bit. P.S. I am not adjust myself to use this Stack Over Flow System.this is the first time to use.How Can I thank you for this advice?

Comment: You're welcome; you can accept my answer by clicking the tick. when you get enough reputation you'll also be able to upvote. see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask for help

Comment: Thank you for your kindness,Mr.CharlesB. I understand how to use this system (^_^).

Answer (score 0):

Accordng to the MSDN article covering LoadResource, the first parameter should be optional.

For me LoadResource produces error code 193 when I try to access a resource located in another exe file, without passing the hModule parameter.

Doesn't work:

```
HRSRC hResource = FindResource(LoadLibrary(strFileName.c_str()), MAKEINTRESOURCE(1), RT_STRING);
HGLOBAL hResHandle = LoadResource(NULL, hResource);
```

Works like a charm:

```
HMODULE hExe = LoadLibrary(strFileName.c_str());
HRSRC hResource = FindResource(hExe, MAKEINTRESOURCE(1), RT_STRING);
HGLOBAL hResHandle = LoadResource(hExe, hResource);
```